# Arcpy.addTable() error

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, field-mapping

I am having a little trouble debugging an ex-coworkers code.

I am receiving this error:

```
RuntimeError: FieldMappings: Error in adding table to field mappings
```

The code:

```py
CIP_FDFC_Tuple =  [('Cadastre', 'Installation', 'Cadastre\\Installation'),
              ('Cadastre', 'LandParcel', 'Cadastre\\LandParcel'),
              ('General', 'Wall', 'General\\Wall')]

env.workspace =r"C:\\Users\\1468394150E\\AppData\\Roaming\\ESRI\\Desktop10.1\\ArcCatalog\\CIP-GIO FUSED.sde" #sys.argv[1]
inputgdb = env.workspace

#Loop through CIP datasets and feature classes
#env.workspace = inputgdb 
for (a,b,c) in CIP_FDFC_Tuple:
    inFeature = inputgdb + "\\" + c
    arcpy.AddMessage( "inFeature: "+ inFeature)

    #Remove GlobalID within SDE feature tables
    fieldmappings = arcpy.FieldMappings()
    fieldmappings.addTable(c)
    fieldmappings.removeFieldMap(fieldmappings.findFieldMapIndex("GLOBALID"))
    #Copying Feature class as a layer into fused gdb
    arcpy.AddMessage("Copying " + c + " feature layer records")
    arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion( inFeature, tempWorkspace, c,  whereClauseAll)
```

Answer (score 2):

The error occurs on the line

```
   fieldmappings.addTable(c)
```

Because you are trying to add a table `c` which is `Cadastre\\Installation`. arcpy doesn't know in which geodatabase feature class is located, so you need to either specify the full path to the feature class or the `env.workspace`.

If you add a line in the beginning of the script:

`arcpy.env.workspace = inputgdb`

the script will run OK.

Another thing is that when running `FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion` you need to supply the `field_mapping` parameter which represents updated field mapping. In your code, it's the `fieldmappings` variable.

Suggestion:

Use `os.path.join` for joining geodatabase path, feature dataset name and feature class name such as

`inFeature = os.path.join(inputgdb,a,b)`

which would give you correct path. You wouldn't need to use a `c` because you have the feature dataset name and the feature class name already in `a` and `b`.

Comment: I believe I neglected to add something important. Please accept my apologies. The current code has this:      env.workspace = r"C:\\Users\\1468394150E\\AppData\\Roaming\\ESRI\\Desktop10.1\\ArcCatalog\\CIP-GIO FUSED.sde" #sys.argv[1]
inputgdb = env.workspace

Comment: No problem! Could you please update your question and put the code into the right position there?

Comment: done, thanks. I do see now that maybe I need to add a \\ in front of "cadaster\\Installation" so that arcpy see's "CIP-GIO FUSED.sde\\cadastre\\Installation"

Comment: You don't need to make any modifications, the code that is currently in the question body will run.